# Вывод значений ассоциативного массива

Tags: php, массивы

Для вывода значений массива я использую цикл foreach.
В основном массиве содержатся массивы фильмов которые содержат данные о фильмах. 
Отталкиваясь от даты выхода и даты первого показа я вывожу фильмы с определенными метками. Вот так:

```
$isShowBeforePremiere = $firstSeansDate < $releaseDate ? true : false;
$isPpresale = $firstSeansDate > $nextThursday ? true : false;
$isUsual = $nowDate === $firstSeansDate ? true : false;

if($isShowBeforePremiere) {
    echo 'это допремьера <br/>';
}
if($isPpresale) {
    echo 'это предпродажа <br/>';
}
if($isUsual) {
    echo 'это обычный фильм <br/>';
}
```

Но, фильмы идут в разнобой и типы фильмов перемешиваются.
Раньше я делал три цикла, каждый из которых выводил определенный тип.
Но массив довольно громоздкий и мне хочется переделать это по человечески, чтоб не проходить по массиву три раза. Подскажите как правильно это реализовать, пожалуйста.

Comment: Каким образом формируется этот массив?

Comment: этот массив я получаю по api в том виде в котором он есть.

Comment: Может возможно при проходе, на лету переместить элемент массива в конец и добавить к нему ключ и значение,  к примеру isUsual => true, а потом когда цикл вновь дойдет до этого элемента проверить, если есть такой ключ, то не отправлять в конец а вывести?

Comment: Можно сделать 4-й массив с тремя ключами `Array("before"=>Array(), "pre"=>Array(), "usual"=>Array())`. Пройтись по основному массиву один раз, раскидывая каждый фильм в соответсвующий подмассив нового...

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы не гонять основной массив три раза, я бы предложил при первом проходе выводить то что нужно выводить именно при первом проходе, а индексы остальных записей сохранять в дополнительный массивы (для второго и третьего прохода соответственно).

А потом уже пройтись по этим вспомогательным массивам и вывести записи для них.

Как вариант - изучить АПИ откуда берутся данные - возможно там есть функционал сортировки данных.

Ну или подумать и найти признак, по кторому можно отсортировать исходный массив. Думаю что функция `uasort` может помочь.

Comment: api изучил вдоль и поперек. К сожалению там нет такой возможности. По поводу uasort я думал, это было легко, когда мне надо было просто отсортировать по дате релиза, но но с этой задачей, есть три признака, которые я могу получить только при проходе массива.

Comment: @Joe можно попробовать при сортировке брать не просто поле, а делать вычисление на основании нескольких полей и потом сортировать